# Creating an in-memory Database and Table if not exist

Tags: sqlite, database-connection

I am trying to create an in-memory DB using sqllite

```
Connection inMemConn = null;
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        inMemConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:inMemDB.db");
        Statement DBCreateTable = inMemConn.createStatement();
        DBCreateTable.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS inMemDB" );
        DBCreateTable.executeUpdate("USE inMemDB");
        DBCreateTable. executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pNumbertable");
```

and i am trying to populate it with some Java Objects

```
final String DBinsert = "INSERT INTO pNumbertable VALUES(?,?)";
        PreparedStatement DBAddObjects = inMemConn.prepareStatement(DBinsert);      

        for (int i = 0; i < List.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < List2.size(); j++) {

                DBAddObjects.setObject(1, XList.get(i)[0]);
                DBAddObjects.setObject(2, YList.get(j)[1]);
                DBAddObjects.executeUpdate();           
            }
        }

        DBAddObjects.close();
        inMemConn.close();
```

But, while running the code, I get the following error.

```
near "DATABASE": syntax error
```

Also, is it the correct way to create an in-mem DB.?

Comment: "jdbc:sqlite:file.db" is not in-memory sqlite db, it will be saved in file.db.
You can create in-memory db using "jdbc:sqlite::memory:" jdbc connection string.

Comment: Also you don't have to "CREATE DATABASE", inMemDB.db **is** database. Just skip "create database" step.

Comment: Now, its throwing an error for create table statement `DBCreateTable. executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pNumbertable");` The error thrown is `near "pNumbertable": syntax error` Even using `DBCreateTable.executeUpdate("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE sellerPartNumbertable");` did not solve the problem.

Comment: You have to provide column definitions:  
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table(x INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, y INTEGER);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is on CREATE DATABASE statement in SQLite; databases are created by creating a connection with the desired file name.

You have opened (or created) a database with the file name `inMemDB.db`.

To create an [in-memory database](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html), you must use the special file name `:memory:` instead:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::memory:");
```

Comment: Now, its throwing an error for create table statement `DBCreateTable. executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pNumbertable");` The error thrown is `near "pNumbertable": syntax error`